Fourier transform of generalized Zener bodies
The generalized Zener bodies is
$$c(t) = c^{(R)}[1-\frac{1}{L}\sum\limits_{\gamma=1}^L (1-\frac{\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\epsilon}{\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma})e^{-t/\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma}]H(t), $$
where c(t) is the bulk modulus, which reduces in time. It has L-th Zener bodies.
$\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\epsilon$ and $\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma$ are relaxation times of strain and stress. Finally, H(t) is the heaviside function.
In given Fourier transform table,
$$F(H(t)) = \pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{j\omega}, $$
$$F(e^{-bt}H(t)=\frac{1}{b+j\omega}, $$
where j is imaginary unit. Taking Fourier transform on generalized Zener bodies is
$$F(c(t))=c^{(R)}[\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{j\omega}-\frac{1}{L}\sum\limits_{\gamma=1}^L (1-\frac{\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\epsilon}{\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma})\frac{1}{1/\tau^{\gamma,c}_\sigma+j\omega} $$
$$c(\omega)=c^{(R)}[\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{j\omega}-\frac{1}{L}\sum\limits_{\gamma=1}^L \frac{\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma-\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\epsilon}{1+j\omega\tau^{(\gamma , c)}_\sigma} $$
Consequently, the last equation is the generalized Zener bodies in the frequency domain. To check the result, I made the numerical conversion, but results didn't match. Did I made any mistake during derivation?, or do you think that derivation is right?

The derivation looks right to me. Can you say more about the the mismatch you're observing?

Comparison of time domain(First eq, Blue line) and frequency domain (ifft(last eq), Orange line)
It could be the problems of my code application, so I'm not sure the derivation is right.

How is this an answer?
